# Elastic Search match query returning exact match in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-7

I Am searching elasticsearch with the below match query, the match query is returning exact match which is a surprise to me because it should not return exact matches atleast that is what is mentioned in documentation : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/query-dsl-match-query.html

I am using elasticsearch 7.8.1

Please find my query below :

```
get pin_code/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "Village/Locality name": "Burj"
      }
   }
}
```

Above query returns documents where "Village/Locality name" is "Burj" But I want to return the documents where Village/Locality name is like below:

```
Burj
Burj Seda
Burj Khalifa
Burj zedran
```

Please provide your valuable suggestions .

Comment: What are the results when you run the query?
Is the field name "Village/Locality name" ?
About match query: The match query is of type boolean. It means that the text provided is analyzed and the analysis process constructs a boolean query from the provided text. The operator parameter can be set to or and to control the boolean clauses (defaults to or)

Answer (score 0):

I considered "Village/Locality name" is your complete field name. Now the problem might be with your mappings of the respective field of your index. If you found below mapping -

GET pin_code/_mapping

```
{
  "pin_code" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "Village/Locality name" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Change it as below -

```
{
  "pin_code" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "Village/Locality name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can run your query and can see all mentioned keywords return in your query response.

```
GET pin_code/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "Village/Locality name": "Burj"
      }
   }
}
```